# É possível executar vários cenários de teste ao mesmo tempo com Selenium Webdriver?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Nos meus testes, um cenário só inicia após o outro ser finalizado e causa mt lentidão na execução dos testes. É possível executar vários cenários de teste ao mesmo tempo com Selenium Webdriver?

Comment: Possível é, a vários motivos para lentidão entre elas estão, *Configurações de Hardware*, *Sistema Operacional*, entre outros fatores.

Comment: Como posso fazer essa paralisação entre os testes?

Comment: [edite](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/246902/edit) sua pergunta e [forneça um código Mínimo, Completo e Verificável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) e coloque também a *Tag* da *Linguagem de Programação* que você esta usando.